# Regex to replace %2B with underscore in filenames

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I am trying to replace all occurences of `%2B` in filenames with `_`.

For example:

Before: `/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Moreton%2Bwindow.jpg`

After: `/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Moreton_window.jpg`

There may be many occurences of `%2B` between `/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/` and `.jpg`.

This is what I have so far:

```
(?<=\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/10\/.)(%2B)(?=.\.jpg)
```

Replaced with:
`_`

But it's not working. I will be doing this replace in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe MySQL supports regex-based string-replacement — and I don't see anything like that in the documentation — but you can write an expression like this:

```
CASE WHEN path_plus_filename REGEXP '^/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/.*[.]jpg$'
     THEN REPLACE(path_plus_filename, '%2B', '_')
     ELSE path_plus_filename
 END
```

which returns `path_plus_filename`, but replacing every `%2B` with `_` if (and only if) the whole thing matches `^/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/.*[.]jpg$`.

Or, if you want an `UPDATE` statement rather than a query, you can write:

```
UPDATE table_that_contains_path_plus_filename_column
   SET path_plus_filename = REPLACE(path_plus_filename, '%2B', '_')
 WHERE path_plus_filename REGEXP '^/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/.*[.]jpg$'
;
```

---

**Edited to add:** By the way, this is neither here nor there, but — the problem with your regex is that it requires `%2B` to be preceded by `/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/` plus *exactly* one character, and followed by *exactly* two characters plus `jpg`. To get some flexibility in the number of characters allowed, you'd need to use `.*` ("zero or more characters") or `.+` ("one or more characters") or `.{5,20}` ("between five and twenty characters") or whatnot.

Comment: Thanks but I'm having trouble - if I do this:
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_content` REGEXP '.*/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/.*[.]jpg$'

it returns no rows but if I omit '[.]jpg' it works.. but I need the .jpg bit to be in there

Comment: On second thoughts, I don't think the SQL query method will work, since I only want to replace the image file paths that contain '%2B', not HTML links that also might contain it. Using the UPDATE function will replace that string not just in image paths but in links too, where they exist in the same table cell. I guess if MySQL cannot support REGEX replacements then it can't be done.

Comment: @JoeSmalley: Yeah, the `$` means "end-of-string". I didn't realize that there was more in this field than just the image-path. That makes this much harder. I think you'll have to write a stored-procedure that really examines the value and performs replacements more intelligently.